# Cascade delete and detached objects in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, poco

Here is a part of an [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) model

[image: db model]

Basically I have **items** that can have multiple **previews**, and each preview has a thumbnail (stored in the blob field *Data* in *PreviewThumbnail*).

I am using self-tracking [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) proxies and the repository pattern.
Foreign key constraints are enforced both in the database and the Entity Framework model.
Now, because the **PreviewThumbnail** objects contain byte arrays I do not want Entity Framework to track them, I just want to be able to load the bite [?] array and do stuff with it and dispose of it in a while. And this is the relevant code:

```
public ObjectSet<PreviewThumbnail> PreviewThumbnails {
    get {
        if (mPreviewsThumbnailsSet == null) {
            mPreviewsThumbnailsSet = CreateObjectSet<PreviewThumbnail>("PreviewThumbnails");
            mPreviewsThumbnailsSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
        }
        return mPreviewsThumbnailsSet;
    }
}
```

And this is how I get the bytes for a given preview:

```
public byte[] LoadImagePreviewThumbnail(Preview preview) {
    var thumb = this.ObjectContext.PreviewThumbnails.First(t => t.Preview.ID == preview.ID);
    return thumb.Data;
}
```

Now then, as the scene is set up, I am trying to get the delete cascade to work - if an **Item** is deleted, all its **Previews** should also be deleted along with their **PreviewThumbnails**.
Sound good, but when an **Item** is deleted, the following exception is thrown:

> A relationship from the 'FK_PreviewThumbnails_0' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'PreviewThumbnails' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

If I remove the Cascade OnDelete action from 'FK_PreviewThumbnails_0' exactly the same exception is thrown.

More surprisingly (at least to me), when I change the multiplicity on the **PreviewThumbnail** end (meaning a preview could not have a thumbnail, which of course is not valid) exactly the same exception is thrown.

The last thing I tried was to completely remove the association between **Preview** and **PreviewThumbnail** in the Framework model (after all I can do without it), but that is not valid - the foreign key in the database should be backed by an association in the conceptual model.

Is there a nice way out of this situation?

Comment: In case you remove the "no tracking code" does it works fine then ?

Comment: actually no, because I have lazy loading enabled